# Getting a .csv to overlay on a .shp file

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

Struggling to get my locations plotted over top of a shapefile

.csv has four columns ; site, reach, lat, long

I've managed to get this code to work on another project but there has to be something im missing as the map comes out only with the shapefile (water shed catchment).

See code below..

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(cmocean)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(sf)
library(ggsn)
library(plotrix)


#-------------------------#
# Pre-processing the data #
#-------------------------#
setwd("~/GitHub/Water_Chemistry")
water <- read.csv("Input/Locations.csv")
head(water)

# Reorder plotting order
water$Reach <- factor(water$Reach, levels = c("Estuary - Lower Clarence", "Orara", "Mid - Clarence", "Mann - Nymboida", "Upper Clarence"))

# Load catchment shapefile:
catch <- st_read("Input/shapefile/MultiAttributeClarence.shp") # Use sf package (keep projection!)
head(catch)
catch[catch$LandCode == "f5k",]
catchrivers <- catch[catch$LandCode == "f5k",]
class(catchrivers)
catchrivers



#-------------------------#
#     Creating Figure 1   #
#-------------------------#

# Map receivers in the Clarence
plotA <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(data = water, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, fill = Reach), pch = 21, stroke = 1.0) +
  geom_sf(data = catchrivers,  
          fill = 'gray60', alpha = 0.4,
          size = 0.07, colour = "black") +
   coord_sf(xlim = c(151.65, 153.5), ylim = c(-28.25, -30.5), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(cmocean('phase')(6)[1:5])) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = cmocean('thermal')(15)[1:5]) +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", fill = "Reach",
       colour = "Reach") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 1)) +
  ggsn::scalebar(x.min = 153, x.max = 153.3, y.min = -30.30, y.max = -30.35, transform = TRUE, 
                 box.fill = c("black", "white"), box.color = "black", st.color = "black",
                 dist_unit = "km", dist = 10, st.dist = 0.3, st.size = 3, height = 0.15, border.size = 0.3)
plotA
```

Would like to have the points from the .csv plotted over top of the shapefile. Unfortunately only seeing the shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

You could transform your .csv into an `sf` object using `st_as_sf`.

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)


set.seed(1)

world <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")

df <- tibble(lon = runif(20,0,100),
             lat = runif(20,0,100))

df_sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs=4326)


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  geom_sf(data = df_sf, colour = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This has helped! Managed to get the points overtop of the catchment :)