# Converting latitude and longitude to coordindates

Tags: r, coordinates, r-sf, r-sp, tmap

I manually entered latitude and longitude in my dataset in csv format and imported the dataset to R. I am trying convert the variable `lat` and `lng` into coordinates so that I can use `tmap` or `geom_sf` to plot it as a map in R. But I am not able to do so. I used the following code to convert the variables `lat` and `lng` to coordinates and it did not work. I am attaching the image of my dataset here. can someone help me? I want to plot variable `lat` and `lng` on a map.

```
cov2 <- st_as_sf(co1, coords = c('lng', 'lat'))


ggplot(co1) + 
  geom_sf()

coordinates(co1)<-6:7
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mahir Bhatt, as explicitly indicated when asking a question, please do not provide your data as an image. Please edit your question to provide reproducible code using something like `dput(your_data)` or creating a sample dataset.

Comment: You are converting `col` to `sf` and storing it in `cov2`, but then you are trying to plot your old `col`, not `cov2`

Comment: cov2%>%tm_shape() + tm_polygons(col= "Type"). I tried using this but this is also not working.

Comment: Again, you have have `ggplot(co1)` instead of `ggplot(cov2)` in your question. If you just want to have some points plotted, you can start with: `read_csv("lat, lng\n32.77610, -89.12210\n41.83730, -87.63620\n") %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = st_crs(4326) ) %>% ggplot() + geom_sf()`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I am able to plot points using this but I want to have them on a global map, not just as points on coordinate plane. Is that possible?

Comment: @jpsmith sorry for the inconvenience. Will keep that in mind next time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74412129/646761

Answer (score 0):

Based on the points defined by @margusl you can do the following:

```
library(tmap)
data("World")

points <- read_csv("lat, lng\n32.77610, -89.12210\n41.83730, -87.63620\n") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = st_crs(4326))

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons(col = "gray", 
              alpha = .5) +
  tm_shape(points) +
  tm_bubbles(col = "red", 
             border.col = "black", 
             size = .5)
```

[image]